# Need to convert mysql to SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some code I need to be converted from MYSQL to SQL. I did my best to convert it but SSMS does not like it. I have a select statement and I need the generated column 'COI STATUS' to be the final column.

```
Declare @test varchar(200)
SET @test = '9-12-2019'
IIf(@test Between Date()-15 And Date()-1,"Grace Period",
IIf(@test Between Date() And Date()+30,"Going to Expire",IIf(@test>Date()+30,"Active COI",
IIf(@test<Date()-15,"Expired COI","Other")))) AS [COI Status]
```

If variable @test is within now and -15 days from now I need the cell to say "Going to Expire". If it is more then 30 days from now it needs to say "Active COI". If the date is more then 15 days old I need it to say "Expired COI".

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a DATE type for something like this?

Comment: When you say SQL, do you mean M$SQL?

Comment: It would be nice to see the MySQL

Comment: It will be a date type field. Yes, I am referring to Microsoft SQL. The working MYSQL is below.

IIf([jot_form_data]![Exp_Date] Between Date()-15 And Date()-1,"Grace Period",IIf([jot_form_data]![Exp_Date] Between Date() And Date()+30,"Going to Expire",IIf([jot_form_data]![Exp_Date]>Date()+30,"Active COI",IIf([jot_form_data]![Exp_Date]<Date()-15,"Expired COI","Other")))) AS [COI Status

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
Declare @test varchar(200)
SET @test = '9-12-2019'
IIf(@test Between Convert(Date, )-15 And Convert(Date, )-1,"Grace Period",
IIf(@test Between Convert(Date, ) And Convert(Date, )+30,"Going to Expire",IIf(@test>Convert(Date, )+30,"Active COI",
IIf(@test<Convert(Date, )-15,"Expired COI","Other")))) AS [COI Status]
```

Comment: This returns the error "Incorrect syntax near 'IIF'" I am running it on Microsoft SQL SSMS

Answer (score 0):

I decided that a case statement was what I was looking for.

```
`Declare @test DATE
SET @test = '08-20-2019';
Select COMPANY, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, PHONENUMBER, COIEXP, STATE, STATUS, 
Case 
 WHEN COIEXP Between GetDate()-1 and GetDate()-15 THEN 'Grace Period'
 WHEN COIEXP Between GetDate() and GetDate()+30 then 'Going to Expire'
 WHEN COIEXP > GetDate()+30 then 'Active COI'
 WHEN COIEXP < GetDate()-15 then 'Expired COI'
 ELSE '' END AS 'COI STATUS'
FROM mytable`
```